# Spark Streaming job wont schedule additional work

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

Spark 2.1.1 built for Hadoop 2.7.3

Scala 2.11.11

Cluster has 3 Linux RHEL 7.3 Azure VM's, running Spark Standalone Deploy Mode (no YARN or Mesos, yet)

I have created a very simple SparkStreaming job using IntelliJ, written in Scala. I'm using Maven and building the job into a fat/uber jar that contains all dependencies.

When I run the job locally it works fine. If I copy the jar to the cluster and run it with a master of local[2] it also works fine. However, if I submit the job to the cluster master it's like it does not want to schedule additional work beyond the first task. The job starts up, grabs however many events are in the Azure Event Hub, processes them successfully, then never does anymore work. It does not matter if I submit the job to the master as just an application or if it's submitted using supervised cluster mode, both do the same thing.

I've looked through all the logs I know of (master, driver (where applicable), and executor) and I am not seeing any errors or warnings that seem actionable. I've altered the log level, shown below, to show ALL/INFO/DEBUG and sifted through those logs without finding anything that seems relevant.

It may be worth noting that I had previously created several jobs that connect to Kafka, instead of the Azure Event Hub, using Java and those jobs run in supervised cluster mode without an issue on this same cluster. This leads me to believe that the cluster configuration isn't an issue, it's either something with my code (below) or the Azure Event Hub.

Any thoughts on where I might check next to isolate this issue? Here is the code for my simple job.

Thanks in advance.

Note: conf.{name} indicates values I'm loading from a config file. I've tested loading and hard-coding them, both with the same result.

```
package streamingJob

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils
import org.joda.time.DateTime

object TestJob {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    sparkConf.setAppName("TestJob")

    // Uncomment to run locally
    //sparkConf.setMaster("local[2]")

    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val streamingContext: StreamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, Seconds(1))

    val readerParams = Map[String, String] (
      "eventhubs.policyname" -> conf.policyname,
      "eventhubs.policykey" -> conf.policykey,
      "eventhubs.namespace" -> conf.namespace,
      "eventhubs.name" -> conf.name,
      "eventhubs.partition.count" -> conf.partitionCount,
      "eventhubs.consumergroup" -> conf.consumergroup
    )

    val eventData = EventHubsUtils.createDirectStreams(
      streamingContext,
      conf.namespace,
      conf.progressdir,
      Map("name" -> readerParams))

    eventData.foreachRDD(r => {
      r.foreachPartition { p => {
        p.foreach(d => {
          println(DateTime.now()  + ": " + d)
        }) // end of EventData
      }} // foreachPartition
    }) // foreachRDD

    streamingContext.start()
    streamingContext.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Here is a set of logs from when I run this as an application, not cluster/supervised.

```
/spark/bin/spark-submit --class streamingJob.TestJob --master spark://{ip}:7077 --total-executor-cores 1 /spark/job-files/fatjar.jar

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/11/06 17:52:04 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.1
17/11/06 17:52:05 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/11/06 17:52:05 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
17/11/06 17:52:05 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
17/11/06 17:52:05 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
17/11/06 17:52:05 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
17/11/06 17:52:05 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/11/06 17:52:06 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 44384.
17/11/06 17:52:06 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/11/06 17:52:06 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/11/06 17:52:06 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/11/06 17:52:06 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/11/06 17:52:06 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-b5e2c0f3-2500-42c6-b057-cf5d368580ab
17/11/06 17:52:06 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
17/11/06 17:52:06 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/11/06 17:52:06 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/11/06 17:52:06 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://{ip}:4040
17/11/06 17:52:06 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/spark/job-files/fatjar.jar at spark://{ip}:44384/jars/fatjar.jar with timestamp 1509990726989
17/11/06 17:52:07 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://{ip}:7077...
17/11/06 17:52:07 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /{ip}:7077 after 72 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
17/11/06 17:52:07 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20171106175207-0000
17/11/06 17:52:07 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 44624.
17/11/06 17:52:07 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on {ip}:44624
17/11/06 17:52:07 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/11/06 17:52:07 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20171106175207-0000/0 on worker-20171106173151-{ip}-46086 ({ip}:46086) with 1 cores
17/11/06 17:52:07 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, {ip}, 44624, None)
17/11/06 17:52:07 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20171106175207-0000/0 on hostPort {ip}:46086 with 1 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
17/11/06 17:52:07 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager {ip}:44624 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, {ip}, 44624, None)
17/11/06 17:52:07 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, {ip}, 44624, None)
17/11/06 17:52:07 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, {ip}, 44624, None)
17/11/06 17:52:07 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20171106175207-0000/0 is now RUNNING
17/11/06 17:52:08 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
```